# Why is Gyroscope needed if Quaternions is present?

Tags: gyroscope, quaternions

If the Quaternions provide accurate orientation, Why do the sensors also provide gyroscope data?

Comment: We need more context. What platform is this? What sensors are you using?

Comment: Its a general question related to motion tracking. If the quaternion data provides the change from the local frame of reference to the global frame of reference. Why do the commercial sensors that provide the quaternion data also provide gyroscope data?

Comment: The quaternions are computed from the gyro measurements.